# sklearn exception error: fitfailed warning from GridSearchCV in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, scikit-learn

I want to optimize hyperparams of CNN model for the image classification tasks (multi- class). To do so, I used `gridSearchCV` from `sklearn` but I always have bunch of warnings and values error as follow:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:552: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 209, in fit
    return super(KerasClassifier, self).fit(x, y, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 151, in fit
    history = self.model.fit(x, y, **fit_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 593, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 646, in _process_inputs
    x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2383, in _standardize_user_data
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2489, in _standardize_tensors
    y, self._feed_loss_fns, feed_output_shapes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 810, in check_loss_and_target_compatibility
    ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
**ValueError:** A target array with shape (500, 99) was passed for an output of shape (None, 100) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

  FitFailedWarning)
```

to me, this bug may raised from sklearn and I am not sure how can I get rid of it for optimal parameter findings. Is there any way to fix those? Any thought?

**minimal example**:

this is just minimal example:

```
X = np.random.randn(1000, 2048)
y = np.array([i for i in range(100)]*10) # <- 1D array with target labels

def myCNN():
  model = keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, input_dim=2048, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
  

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=myCNN)
parameters = { 'epochs': [10, 20, 30],
               'batch_size':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8] }              

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,
                           param_grid=parameters,
                           scoring='accuracy',
                           cv=2)

grid_search = grid_search.fit(X, y)
print (grid_search.best_params_)
```

from the above-pasted error message, I could assume that error may be traced back from sklearn. Is there any one point me how to fix this? any thoughts?

Comment: I copy&pasted the above code and run it without any error. The problem is probably somewhere else. Can you post the full code?

Comment: I don't see any errors either.

Comment: @taha I am gonna share source code with colab shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use Bayesian optimization from `bayes_opt` which is much more efficient than `GridSearchCV` and perform fast. Here is the quick example of how you can use Bayesian optimization:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

def myCNN(fully_conn_size, len_layer_conv, kernel_size, learning_rate, pooling_size, multiply,dropout_rate, beta, activation, batch_normalization, batch_size = 10):
  model = keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, input_dim=2048, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model


accbest = 0.0
NN_BAYESIAN = BayesianOptimization(myCNN, 
                              {'fully_conn_size': (16, 128),
                               'len_layer_conv': (3, 5),
                               'kernel_size': (2, 7),
                               'learning_rate': (0.0001, 1),
                               'pooling_size': (2, 4),
                               'multiply': (1, 3),
                               'dropout_rate': (0.1, 0.99),
                               'beta': (0.000001, 0.49),
                               'activation': (0, 2),
                               'batch_normalization': (0, 1)
                              })
NN_BAYESIAN.maximize(init_points = 20, n_iter = 40, acq = 'ei', xi = 0.0)
```

I guess you should customize parameters for your models then run Bayesian optimization like I showed above. good luck and let me know if you have any question.